# Change Charset of SSIS package from Unicode to Latin 1

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis

I created an SSIS package which makes queries my DB and exports the Result to a CSV File, in order to import the data into the DB of another system B (which I don't have access to). According to the administration of system B the CSV file structure is correct but for some reason the import fails. He also told me, that they use `ISO-8859-1 (latin 1)` as charset, while Flat File Connection at the SSIS package is set to `Unicode`. When I try to change the Code page Attribute to `1252 (ANSI - Latin 1)` it fails, since some of my columns are of data type `Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]`. How can I convert those values so I can change the charset to Latin 1?

Comment: Did you try the Data Conversion Transformation?

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't work properly, because it would simply add the converted columns to the existing, non converted columns. I also tried using the Derived Column Transformation using `(DT_STR,20,1252)(Column)` to convert a `DT_WSTR` and using `(DT_TEXT,1252)(Column)` to convert a `DT_NTEXT` but not working properly, either. Instead of converting a single column, it seems as it converts all colums together into a single column...

Answer (score 2):

Although my question doesn't seem to be very popular, I'm going to leave the link to the solution here, in case someone else has the same problem some day:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7842f04-d496-4e8b-9c43-8efa3840f7f2/change-charset-of-ssis-package-from-unicode-to-latin-1